# How to use use variables for image folder path

Tags: javascript, jquery, var

Can I have an image folder path and an url path in two variables (E.g `var path = css/image/` and `var urlpath = /pic/funny/`) and append them before every image and url respectively so that I don't have to repeat the pathes for every image in  `var picData`?

```
Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
                var s = [];
                while (this.length) s.push(this.splice(Math.random() * this.length, 1));
                while (s.length) this.push(s.pop());
                return this;
            }

            var picData = [
                ['img1','url_1'],
                ['img2','url_2'],
                ['img3','url_3'],
                ['img4','url_4'],
                ['img5','url_5'],
                ['img6','url_6'],
                ['img7','url_7']];

            picO = new Array();
            randIndex = new Array();  //array of random indexes
            for(i=0; i < picData.length; i++){
                picO[i] = new Image();
                picO[i].src = picData[i][0];
                picO[i].alt = picData[i][1];
                randIndex.push(i);
            }
            randIndex.shuffle();
            window.onload=function(){
                var mainImgs = document.getElementById('carouselh').getElementsByTagName('img');


                for(i=0; i < mainImgs.length; i++){
                    mainImgs[i].src = picO[randIndex[i]].src; //assign a random image
                    mainImgs[i].parentNode.href = picData[randIndex[i]][1];
                    mainImgs[i].alt = picData[randIndex[i]][1];
                }

            }
```

I have tried something like `mainImgs[i].src = path.picO[randIndex[i]].src;` but I can't get the syntax right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `+` to combine variables, not `.`

```
var a = "Some";
var b = "day";
var c = " we are gone.";

alert(a + " " + b + c);
```

Or as then by your example:

```
mainImgs[i].src = path + picO[randIndex[i]].src;
```

You also need to quote your variables:

```
var urlpath = "/pic/funny/";
```

Comment: @Tomanow: Quote: *I have tried something like `mainImgs[i].src = path.picO[randIndex[i]].src;` [...]*.

Comment: It works. Problem solved! I have to put the variable in `window.onload=function(){`

Comment: @user35295: You could also put your script at bottom of page or use `addEventListener("load")` on document. As you are using jQuery you could use `$(document).ready(function(){ /* Put your code for getting DOM elements here. */ })` Ref. http://api.jquery.com/ready/